# Linux framebuffer not updating when using KD_GRAPHICS

Tags: c, linux, graphics, linux-kernel, framebuffer

I've been trying to do some old-school drawing on the Linux framebuffer. I'm aware this is not the "modern" way to do things but exploring it out of curiosity. I am confused that my screen does not seem to update as expected when using `KD_GRAPHICS` mode.

Running the following program from the console to paint the screen white, the framebuffer will display a section of white on the screen, then stop updating for the duration of the `sleep()`, then briefly flash white before returning to `KD_TEXT` mode. If I comment out the `KDSETMODE` changes, then the framebuffer is painted white immediately except for the cursor being visible (which I don't want) and stays white for the expected 5 seconds. Can someone enlighten me why I am not seeing screen updates with `KD_GRAPHCIS`?

Machine is running Ubuntu 20.04 with a 5.13.0-52-generic kernel.

```
#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/kd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

uint32_t pixel_color(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b, struct fb_var_screeninfo *vinfo)
{
    return (r<<vinfo->red.offset) | (g<<vinfo->green.offset) | (b<<vinfo->blue.offset);
}

int main()
{
    ioctl(0,KDSETMODE,KD_GRAPHICS);

    struct fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;
    struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;

    int fb_fd = open("/dev/fb0",O_RDWR);

    ioctl(fb_fd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo);
    ioctl(fb_fd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &finfo);

    long screensize = vinfo.yres_virtual * finfo.line_length;

    uint8_t *fbp = mmap(0, screensize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fb_fd, (off_t)0);

    int x,y;

    for (x=0;x<vinfo.xres;x++)
        for (y=0;y<vinfo.yres;y++)
        {
            long location = x * (vinfo.bits_per_pixel/8) + y * finfo.line_length;
            *((uint32_t*)(fbp + location)) = pixel_color(0xFF,0xFF,0xFF, &vinfo);
        }

    sleep(5);

    ioctl(0,KDSETMODE,KD_TEXT);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Modern machine have graphics memory that can be completely distinct from main memory.  A graphics driver can support this with page handlers on writes (it is much more complex than it use to be).  You will have to 'switch' to the 'fb0'.  This is done with 'Alt-VT#'.  Also appears to be some bug.  https://lore.kernel.org/all/8a037d87-5ace-36af-29eb-77a4f8c6df98@gmail.com/T/

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's pretty clear from looking at `lsmod` that my hardware is new enough not to have a physical framebuffer device (the only module I can find related to framebuffers is `fb_sys_fops`) and my framebuffer interface is emulated by the module `drm_kms_helper`. I also found a kernel option called `FB_DEFERRED_IO` that is enabled and have a hunch this may have something to do with the behavior I am witnessing.

Comment: How you solved this?  I am not seeing screen updates as well!@cowile